# Home server with time control

Tags: windows

I want to build myself a computer on wich I will be running some game servers. My question is if there is a way to turn and on the computer via time control, because I don't need it at night? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Older Macs can do that [new ones don't for some stupid reason]. idk of anything for Win that will auto-boot at specific times. [Shutdown is easy, you can do it from batch]

Comment: Try using Wake on LAN

Comment: Thank you! Thats all I Need.

Comment: @John No need for WOL if the PC has a "wake on RTC timer" option in BIOS.